# Regular expression: matching words between white space

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Im trying to do something fairly simple with regular expression in python... thats what i thought at least.

What i want to do is matching words from a string if its preceded and followed by a whitespace. If its at the beginning of the string there is no whitespace required before - if its at the end, dont't search for whitespace either.

Example:

```
"WordA WordB WordC-WordD WordE"
```

I want to match `WordA WordB WordE`.

I only came up with overcomplicated way of doing this...

```
(?<=(?<=^)|(?<=\s))\w+(?=(?=\s)|(?=$))
```

It seems to me there has to be a simple way for such a simple problem....
I figured i can just start with `(?<=\s|^)` but that doesnt seem possible because "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to work in Python as `(?<=^|\s)` is perfectly valid in PCRE, Java and Ruby (and .NET regex supports infinite width lookbehind patterns).

Use

```
(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)
```

It will match 1 or more word chars that are enclosed with whitespace or start/end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EwvuHA/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match once the engine finds a non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match once the engine finds a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: that makes sense! Thanks. I guess searching for nonwhitespace instead of whitespace is much easier.

Comment: Not sure it is easier, but is more efficient.

Comment: I don't understand why simply \s+ surrounding what we need does not work

Comment: @BFurtado Because `\s` consumes a whitespace. Look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EwvuHA/47): there is only one match because the `\s` on both ends *requires* a whitespace on the left and right. `WordA` and `WordE`  have no whitespace on one end. You might think `(\s|^)\w+(\s|$)` will work, but [it does not match consecutive occurrences](https://regex101.com/r/EwvuHA/48) because `(\s|$)` consumes the whitespace after `WordA` and thus `(\s|^)` cannot find the `WordB` match.

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew. I have struggled with regex countless times. Official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html  says nothing about consuming space. There is rather cryptic mention of zero-width (which seems out of context for me, but may resemble what you are kindly explaining. Best,

Comment: @BFurtado I will try to explain it in my Youtube channel and share a link with you (the channel link is in my profile).