# Match exact word and not match if there is a special symbol before

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple regex that matches exact substring in a string:

```
"\bXXX\b"
```

That works cool except 1 case.. if there is special symbol before XXX it matches substring:

```
This is ABC #XXX DEF
```

How I can adjust regex so it doesn't match #XXX?

Comment: What separators *should* be allowed? Space, comma, semicolon, period? What about `This is ABC-XXX`?

Comment: Only spaces allowed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression: matching words between white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189706/regular-expression-matching-words-between-white-space)

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to allow spaces as separators, I would go for

```
(^|(?<= ))XXX($|(?= ))
```

Explanation:

- `(^|(?<= ))`: Start of the line (`^`) or a "positive lookbehind" on a space (`(?<= )`).
- `($|(?= ))`: End of the line (`$`) or a "positive lookahead" on a space (`(?= )`).

The lookbehind/lookahead expressions ensure that the space itself is not part of the match.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a classical whitespace or space boundary.
Involves no alternations and is quicker.

`(?<!\S)XXX(?!\S)`

this will also match XXX at the beginning or end of string.

Also, it might be possible to make it just a space boundary

`(?<![^ ])XXX(?![^ ])`

this will also match XXX at beginning or end of string, but force
space char on either side or *other side* if not.